# Anaconda Autoinstall

Tags: windows-10, anaconda

I used to have Anaconda3 installed some time ago but now I just need a simple python environment.

I've uninstalled Anaconda3 but it keeps reinstalling itself somehow without my knowledge. I don't want this behavior since it conflicts with the main Python installation.
I can't figure out how or what program triggers the auto-install. 
I want to prevent this auto-installation from happening.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

In order to remove the Anaconda installation, you can use the `anaconda-clean` package provided by Anaconda itself.

Install it:

```bsh
conda install anaconda-clean
```

Than you can completly remove anaconda with the following command:

```bsh
anaconda-clean
```

For a **manual uninstall**:

- Use Windows Explorer to delete the envs and pkgs folders prior to running the uninstall in the root of your installation
- In the Control Panel, choose Add or Remove Programs or Uninstall a program, and then select Python 3.6 (Anaconda) or your version of Python.